# W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action

Tags: android, admob

Logs:

```
2021-12-28 13:15:51.438 17135-17135/app.mark.movierecommendor I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:213806100
    2021-12-28 13:15:51.438 17135-17135/app.mark.movierecommendor I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 213806100
    2021-12-28 13:15:51.509 17135-17135/app.mark.movierecommendor W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
    2021-12-28 13:15:51.510 17135-17135/app.mark.movierecommendor I/chatty: uid=10280(app.mark.movierecommendor) identical 1 line
    2021-12-28 13:15:51.510 17135-17135/app.mark.movierecommendor W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
```

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adBannerMainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/add_id_with_dash"
    />
```

Code:

```
// Launch and Initialize Ad Banner
MobileAds.initialize(this@ActionMoviePageActivity)
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
adBannerOther.loadAd(adRequest)
```

That's the second activity, first works fine, but when I press the button to open the second actiivty it gives me this error `W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.`

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a warning. This warning mostly pops up during an Ad refresh, or when the AdView is detached / removed from the view or when the host Activity is destroyed. It won't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by changing the root element from Constraint layout to relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```